# Why are the moderators on this site closing all the good questions?

Tags: discussion

Not everyone is an advanced programmer.  Some of us are new and want to learn the basics and so have basic questions.  I think it is really dickish of you guys to keep closing questions for noobs.

Comment: Are you serious? Well, you didn't get the point of this site then. If you want a discussion, then go to a forum! I know it's a bit stressful when your question gets closed, but don't spam with questions like this here!

Comment: this is a q&a site. try a forum like gamedev.net or the chat here if you don't have an answerable and constructive question to ask.

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) for more infos.

Comment: You are going to need to give examples.

Comment: I *really* want to close this question as a dupe of this one: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/542/request-relax-a-bit-on-moderation-and-dont-be-so-eager-to-shut-down-questions

Answer (score 17):

Basic questions are perfectly acceptable. However, basic questions that lack key information or show complete lack of research get closed. For example (if this question weren't totally off topic and I've voted to close it as such), you ask about why "all the good questions" are being closed, but you don't provide any examples or link to any such questions. In my opinion none of the "good questions" are being closed. You've left out ***key*** information. Am I just supposed to guess which questions you're talking about? If we're left to guess your meaning, you won't get the answers you want.

Same thing goes for many of the questions I assume you're talking about. For example a recent question that was closed:

> **iOS Game Development**
>
> I'm an iOS app developer. But I dont have any gaming development experience and I'm excited to learn and start. Can anyone suggest from where I should start? When I search internt I find lot of buz words. Game engines(like Cocos2D), openGL, iOS GameCenter development etc. I'm confused. From where should I start among those. Appreciate your help in advance. ([Source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29071/ios-game-development) (*deleted*))

This was closed because it's not a real question as defined by the [FAQ](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/faq). The gamedev stackexchange site is for practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. The question above is not really answerable and its practicality is questionable. The OP doesn't say what they want to do. It's like asking: "Should I use a hammer, screwdriver, sailboat or lemon peels?". Without telling you want I want to accomplish, it's pretty difficult to answer. Beyond that the question is so broad it would be impractical to try to give an answer. I can imagine an entire book on how to get started in game development for iOS. Are we supposed to write all that to answer the question?

So, where does one get started? It totally depends on what the person knows already, how they prefer to learn and what their ultimate goal is. It would be impractical to attempt to make a generic answer for everyone and it wouldn't even be a good answer.

Comment: As an aside, I think this is an example of a great answer to a bad question.

Answer (score 5):

It's not that your questions are being closed for being noob-ish or silly, it's that they do not meet the criteria required for the site. A good question has is specific, has a single 'best' answer, is not readily google-able, and is not a repost of a previously asked question.